# What is a key in a linked list?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

Here is a linked list implementation in C.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/linked_list_program_in_c.htm

> ```
> struct node {
>    int data;
>    int key;
>    struct node *next;
> };
> ```

What is a key in a linked list? It seems to me a key is just another piece of data of a node. What is the point of having a key?

Comment: Key is used here to model a dictionary with a linked list.

Comment: Just another piece of data. Not something "necessary" for the linked list data structure to work, as the pointer to the next node is.

Comment: No point in general. This seems to be for illustrative purposes only

Answer (score 4):

It serves no special purpose (in case of linked list implementation) just that it has been given the name `key` and stores an `int`. It is as you said just another piece of data which is relevant (maybe) to the particular implementation.

The variable name seems to misguide us that it is a key or something like that but it is not. We can give it a name of `abc`, `data2` or whatever readable name you can think of.

As pointed out by **greenshade** it is used to model a dictionary using linked list.

Comment: "*It servers no special purpose*" referring a plain linked list you are correct, *but* referring *the code the OP linked* the element `key` *very well* serves a specific purpose. Also please see [this comment to the questions itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42051286/what-is-a-key-in-a-linked-list#comment71274864_42051286).

Comment: @alk.: Ah we can name it `dictKey` also ..so I say that it is just a variable name which may be something else also ...and it has nothing to do with linked list implementation.

Comment: @alk.: I edited so that there is nothing left for confusion. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

A linked list is a chain-like data structure, where each "node" in the chain contains some data, and optionally links to the next node, or to nothing at all if it is the last node. To put it graphically:

```
 ________             ________
|        |           |        |
| Node A |---------->| Node B |--+
|________|           |________|  |
|        |           |        |  |
|   1    |           |   2    |  |
|________|           |________|  |
                                 |
                                 |
+--------------------------------+
|   _______
+->|        |
   | Node C |
   |________|
   |        |
   |   42   |
   |________|
```

The first node in the list is A, and the last ndoe is C. All but the last node point to the next node in the chain. The concept itself i pretty simple. You may implement this chain in C with a code like this:

```
struct node
{
    int          data;
    struct node* next;
};

typedef struct node* linked_list;

struct node node_c = { 42, NULL };
struct node node_b = { 2, &node_c };
struct node node_a = { 1, &node_b };
```

Now, as you might notice, the data structure you describe is a bit different from this one. Concretely, each node has an extra field named `key`. This is most likely in order to implement an inefficient juxtaposition of a map and a linked list, which would act as kind of inefficient dictionary. Did I mention it's way inefficient (this is no joke, don't ever do this in practice)? This is most likely what the original code would have attempted to do:

```
struct node
{
    int          key;
    int          data;
    struct node* next;
};

typedef struct node* map;

map map_insert
(
    map* the_map,
    int  key,
    int  data
)
{
    map previous_node = NULL;
    map current_node = *the_map;

    while( current_node != NULL && current_node->key < key )
    {
        previous_node = current_node;
        current_node = current_node->next;
    }

    map target_node;
    if( current_node == NULL )
    {
        assert( target_node = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) ) );

        target_node->key = key;
        target_node->next = NULL;
    } else if( current_node->key > key )
    {
        assert( target_node = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) ) );

        target_node->key = key;
        target_node->next = current_node;
    } else
    {
        target_node = current_node;
    }

    if( previous_node != NULL )
    {
        previous_node->next = target_node;
    } else
    {
        *the_map = target_node;
    }

    target_node->data = data;
}


int* map_find
(
    map* the_map,
    int  key
)
{
    map current_node = *the_map;
    while( current_node != NULL && current_node->key < key )
    {
        current_node = current_node->next;
    }

    return current_node != NULL && current_node->key == key ? &current_node->data : NULL;
}


void map_remove
(
    map* the_map,
    int  key
)
{
    map previous_node = NULL;
    map current_node = *the_map;

    while( current_node != NULL && current_node->key < key )
    {
        previous_node = current_node;
        current_node = current_node->next;
    }

    if( current_node == NULL || current_node->key > key )
    {
        return;
    }

    map next_node = current_node->next;
    free( current_node );

    if( previous_node != NULL )
    {
        previous_node->next = next_node;
    } else
    {
        *the_map = next_node;
    }
}


void map_new
(
    map* the_map
)
{
    *the_map = NULL;
}


void map_free
(
    map* the_map
)
{
    map current_node = *the_map;
    while( current_node != NULL )
    {
        map next_node = current_node->next;
        free( current_node );
        current_node = next_node;
    }

    *the_map = NULL;
}


void do_pass
(
    map*     the_map,
    unsigned pass
)
{
    printf( "-- PASS %u --\n", pass );

    map current_node = *the_map;
    while( current_node != NULL )
    {
        printf( "%d -> %d\n", current_node->key, current_node->data );
        current_node = current_node->next;
    }
}


int main()
{
    map my_map;
    map_new( &my_map );

    map_insert( &my_map, 0, 1 );
    map_insert( &my_map, 1, 2 );
    map_insert( &my_map, 2, 42 );
    do_pass( &my_map, 1 );

    map_insert( &my_map, 2, 3 );
    map_remove( &my_map, 0 );
    do_pass( &my_map, 2 );

    *map_find( &my_map, 1 ) = 5;
    do_pass( &my_map, 3 );

    map_free( &my_map );
}
```

Outputs:

```
-- PASS 1 --
0 -> 1
1 -> 2
2 -> 42
-- PASS 2 --
1 -> 2
2 -> 3
-- PASS 3 --
1 -> 5
2 -> 3
```